# X is the sum of rolled amounts after throwing dice 500 times. Average value of dots in single throw is 3.5. What is expected value of this event?

Tags: probability, expected-value

$X$ is the sum of rolled amounts after throwing dice $500$ times. Average value of dots in single throw is $3.5$.
What is expected value of this event?

Isn't this just
$$500\times 3.5=1750 \,?$$

Sorry if it's too simple, this task is highly rated on test so it makes me doubt my answer...
Is this correct?

Comment: It really is that simple.

Comment: Just to be clear:  you say you are rolling "dice".  That's a plural, the singular is "die".  If you are throwing a pair of dice the expectation of a single roll is $7$, not $3.5$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the events are independent, let $X_k$ denote the $k$-th roll. Then,
\begin{align}
E[X_1+X_2 +\dots +X_{500}]=E[500 \cdot X_1] = 500E[X_1]
\end{align}
by independence and linearity of expectation.